# why do we need different inner products

Tags: inner-products

There are many inner products for polynomials wrt different weights, such as $\int uv$ and $\int uv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. My question is do these weights have actual meanings in applied context?

After reading the comments, I see that when we have a basis (say chebyshev polynomials), they are orthogonal wrt some weight, and that makes $\int p_ip_jw=\delta_{ij}$. But I think $\int p_ip_jw$ wouldn't be something that we care about? So I still don't quite understand what exactly is simplified.

I guess I am looking for an example where we have motivation to make chebyshev polynomials orthogonal and hence choose to work with the corresponding inner product.

Comment: Could you be slightly more specific? Are you asking the notion of an inner product are useful in applied contexts?

Comment: sometimes it is to "simplify" the calculation e.g., to make sure the basis is orthonormal. But without the context, it is quite hard to tell what you are looking at

Comment: The specific weighted inner product that you refer to make the [Chebyshev polynomials orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality).